# How to go about a cost-effective one-time sale of shares?

Tags: stock-exchanges, shares, inheritance, ireland

I have no real experience of trading in shares, but I have inherited some, and I'd like to find out how to go about selling them. There are a few specific considerations to my case:

- I have a physical share certificate, which I received today.
- The shares are for an Irish company, which seems to be listed on both the Irish stock exchange and the London stock exchange. I live in London, and have both a British bank account and an Irish bank account.
- The share certificate lists the shares as "A Ordinary Shares of €0.125", but the Irish stock exchange lists the share price (today) at more than €100 per share. At today's market price, the shares are worth a little over €20,000.

Ultimately, I want to sell these shares and have the proceeds land in my British bank account.

I am confused around the fact that the company is listed on two different stock exchanges. Are my shares particular to one exchange? Can I sell the shares only in Ireland? If I can choose one country or the other, is there any advantage/disadvantage to one or the other?

I am assuming I have to pay a stockbroker to sell these shares on my behalf. Is that correct? How do I begin to go about that in the most cost-effective way? I don't intend to do any further share trading.

Also worth mentioning - the solicitor who handled the will engaged an accountant to calculate my inheritance tax liability on the shares, which has already been paid to the Irish Revenue.

Comment: Have you checked that those particular shares can still be traded? There have been a few questions posted about old shares with paper certificates.

Comment: @Lawrence yes they can still be traded. The paper certificate I've been issued is recently issued by the company in my name.

Comment: Finally, a good news story. Enjoy your inheritance. If you don’t get a good answer here, call the share registry, give them the certificate number and ask them about your choices for selling the shares.